# В основной полосе прокрутки сайта не видно стрелок

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите, перенёс вёрстку на wordpress и на сайте пропали стрелки на основной прокрутки и ещё при прокрутке начинает выделятся всё содержимое. До переноса было всё ок.
[image: До переноса]

[image: После переноса]

Comment: И как Вы "переносили" верстку на WordPress? Конкретно сам движок ничего с скроллбаром не делает.

Comment: Ну конкретно, это пол дня писать...в кратце - header перенес в файл header.php, зарегистрировал меню через register_nav_menus, изменил меню в верстке на wp_nav_menu ([.......]).  Footer перенес в footer.php,  остальное в index.php. Ну и остальные страницы в соответствующие php файлы через Template name...

Comment: Да, это замечательно) Тему Вы сами писали или использовали скелетон или изменили существующую или это была чайлд тема или что?

Comment: Пустую болванку underscore использовал...

Comment: Только проверил, на опере и фаерфокс всё ок, стрелки есть, содержимое не выделяется...Что ж за феномен такой?

Comment: А плагины какие-то может? Если сменить тему на какую-то из стандартных, то скроллбар тоже такой будет?

Comment: Поменял тему на твенти ту и обратно и всё заработало! Бредовый какой-то лаг...Огромное спасибо за наводку и помощь в целом!)